# Pastry routing and resulting routing gaps?

Tags: routes, p2p

I've been researching the pastry DHT for a personal project and I really like it but the routing has me confused.

The routing is done using prefix routing and uses leafsets for close nodes ( IE nodes with a common prefix with the local node ) and a routeset for more distant nodes.

Now my confusion comes from the following: The DHT is bootstrapped with 5 nodes. The server that functions as a bootstrapper adds every joined node to it's routeset and gives this to every node that joins the DHT afterwards.

So if prefix A joins, the bootstrapper adds it to it's routeset. If prefix F joins after A it will receive the routeset from the bootstrapper which contains A.

What if A needs to Route to F? It will never know of it's existence because the spec does not specify the copying of routing tables between nodes only the leafsets.

This is a small example and i hope it is clear. Is it possible to have a routing gap in pastry?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear with the scenario you have mentioned with regard to routing table maintenance.

But for the following question,

> What if A needs to Route to F? It will never know of it's existence because the spec does not specify the copying of routing tables between nodes only the leafsets.

If A can't find F, A will route to the numerically closest node to F (say node "G") by matching prefix of nodeIds which
indicates the closer hood of peer nodes. Then the node G route to F if F is in its' routing table or it's closest otherwise, and so and so....

Hope the concept is clear with you....